# bottom navigation bar icons won't work properly

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I tried creating a navigation bar for my app in android studio using a menu :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/home_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:title="Home" />
    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/add_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/newPost"
        android:title="Add Post" />
    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/profile_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/profile"
        android:title="Profile" />
</menu>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/myBlack">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    </FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/myGrey"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

but the icons are only appearing only in one shape like a person. If anyone has any idea how do I fix that, thanks in advance.
[An Image represting my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T94a5.png)

I tried looking online for this problem with no sucess